# Background-image of jquery-ui-rotatable

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm using [jquery-ui-rotatable](https://github.com/godswearhats/jquery-ui-rotatable)

Why doesn't the background-image show? `background-image: url('http://icdn.pro/images/en/l/e/left-an-object-rotation-icone-3698-128.png');`

example [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vh8ewq97/1/)

```
.ui-rotatable-handle {
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: url(16x16.png); // not showing
    background-size: 100%;
    left: 2px;
    bottom: 2px;
}
```

How can I make the background-image show?

Comment: In the fiddle there isn't a class called .ui-rotatable-handle.

Comment: @dowomenfart: thanks. it's here jquery.ui.rotatable.min.js (check external links)

Comment: Yeah I see it but check the console. It's not loading the plugins.

Comment: Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/godswearhats/jquery-ui-rotatable/master/jquery.ui.rotatable.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Comment: I've clicked through on the Fiddle and this appears to be working? I'm the author of jquery-ui-rotatable - let me know if this is still an issue for you.